# Internet Explorer Mouseenter possible bug

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am currently at a loss with this particular bit of HTML/CSS problem. I have a carousel that has two absolutely positioned li elements on each side to allow for navigation (previous image/ and next image). These two li elements show up correctly in all browsers other than all versions of IE (7-9), however, in IE the li elements are shown behind the main element, even if I give them a z-index.

I am probably missing something as it was the end of the day and I was very tired, but I cannot seem to figure out why this is.

***What makes this problem even weirder is that the li elements display correctly if I give them a background! As soon as I give them a background-color, they appear in front of the element***

I suspect it may be a bug with IE as it is rare for me to fail to debug a CSS file, however, as I said, I was pretty tired.

**Please ignore the opacity values and display values, these are altered with jQuery. They are completely irrelevant.**

**HTML:**

```
<header id="carousel">
    <div id="carousel-holder">
        <div id="carousel-canvas" style="width: 2364px; ">
            <figure id="more-business" class="">
                <img>
            </figure>
            <figure id="more-money" class="active">
                <img>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul id="arrow-nav">
            <li id="carousel-arrow-previous"><a href="#previous" title="Previous" class="sprite">Previous</a></li>
            <li id="carousel-arrow-next"><a href="#next" title="Next" class="sprite">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
header#carousel {position:relative;width:790px;height:275px;margin:10px auto 0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;}
header#carousel div#carousel-holder {width:788px;height:250px;background:#fff;border:1px solid #999;border-radius:10px;margin:auto;padding:0;overflow:hidden;}
header#carousel div#carousel-canvas {position:static;height:250px;}
header#carousel div#carousel-canvas figure {display:block;position:static;float:left;width:788px;height:250px;border-radius:10px;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;}
header#carousel div#carousel-canvas figure img {width:788px;height:250px;}

header#carousel nav ul#arrow-nav {position:absolute;top:1px;left:1px;width:788px;height:250px;padding:0;margin:0;list-style-type:none;}
header#carousel nav ul#arrow-nav li {position:absolute;display:block;width:200px;height:250px;z-index:10;}
header#carousel nav ul#arrow-nav li#carousel-arrow-previous {top:0;left:0;}
header#carousel nav ul#arrow-nav li#carousel-arrow-next {top:0;right:0;}
header#carousel nav ul#arrow-nav li a {position:absolute;top:50%;margin-top:-35px;display:none;width:50px;height:70px;overflow:hidden;opacity:0;text-indent:-1000px;}
header#carousel nav ul#arrow-nav li#carousel-arrow-previous a {left:20px;background-position:-95px -156px;}
header#carousel nav ul#arrow-nav li#carousel-arrow-next a {right:20px;background-position:-153px -156px;}
```

**EDIT**

I meant to say 'li' not 'div'

**UPDATE**

It seems that the problem may not be with HTML/CSS as I have managed to determine that the element is being displayed at the front of the page. The problem seems to be occuring with jQuery. The 'mouseenter' function appears not to fire when I move my mouse ove the element. Is this a known bug in jQuery?

**SOLUTION**

I have figured out what the problem is. It is to do with the 'hasLayout' of the elements I have mentioned. Because they have a transparent background, the jQuery event is not captured when I place my mouse over them. The solution to this is to set a transparent background with an image.

Please refer to:
[Mouseenter only fired on border of transparent div in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799459/mouseenter-only-fired-on-border-of-transparent-div-in-ie9)

Thank you for all your advice, and sorry to waste your time.

Comment: Just a note: Minifying the CSS (or JS) relevant to your question makes it difficult to follow along. Please de-minify code so it is easily readable when posting a question.

Comment: Also, this: `header#carousel nav ul#arrow-nav li#carousel-arrow-previous` can simply be `#carousel-arrow-previous` if you are using `id` attributes correctly. You don't need a full selector to select a single instance of an element.

Comment: Thanks @JaredFarrish, I am aware that my code can be minified further and it is quite compressed as it is. However, this is just how I like to write my code, it is just what I am used to and familiar with. Everyone has their own way. :-)

Comment: If you're asking for help, please make your code easily readable by others. `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/6w5BN/ If you want to overselect (note, this has nothing to do with *minification*, it's just unnecessary), so be it; the formatting of the code should reflect the needs of those who are trying to help.

Comment: Apologies, I simply copied and pasted it from my source, apart from a few edits in the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is being caused by your "text-indent" being set as a negative on the anchors.  I believe it has something to do with the anchor element controlling its own layout in IE, and not halting the text at its edges. Here is a brief description of the "[hasLayout](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout)" property and some of the issues it can cause in IE. I removed the "text-indent" and the Previous / Next links appeared as normal over any images I set in the carousel.

Comment: Also, as Praveen said, you are using HTML5 tags, so in pre-IE9 browsers your carousel will most likely look a good bit off.

Comment: I suspected this myself but when I removed it, it did not make a difference! I will review my code and double check again but I am pretty sure this is not the problem.

Comment: The HTML 5 is no issue, the entire site looks absolutely fine, this is the only problem. I have written a fix for HTML 5 in unsupported browsers.

Comment: I am afraid this has not solved it. The problem is with the 'li' element, not the a tag. It is this element that is being displayed at the back

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a link, or the actual unedited sample posted somewhere would you?

Comment: Yes but it is a beta and I do not want it made public

Comment: I need to initiate a chat so I can give you the address. Do you know how?

Comment: The problem is to do with the hasLayout thing that you mentioned. I need to set the element to have a zoom of 1. Please see my question edit

Answer (score 1):

Working with your CSS, I've come up:

```
#carousel {
    position: relative;
    width:790px;
    height:275px;
    margin:10px auto 0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

...

#carousel-holder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:788px;
    height:250px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #999;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

...

#carousel nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#arrow-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    width:788px;
    height:250px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
#arrow-nav li {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #dff;
}
#carousel-arrow-previous {
    float: left;
}
#carousel-arrow-next {
    float: right;
}

...


#arrow-nav li a {
    margin-top:-35px;
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    height:70px;
    overflow:hidden;
    opacity:1;
    background: #fdf;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    text-indent:-1000px;
    /*z-index: 1000;*/
}
#carousel-arrow-previous a {
    left: 20px;
    background-position:-95px -156px;
}
#carousel-arrow-next a {
    right: 20px;
    background-position:-153px -156px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6w5BN/1/

Which works in IE9 and IE7/8 compatibility view. What I did was set the `#carousel` element to be `position: relative`, which then allowed me to set `#carousel-holder` and `#carousel nav` to be `position: absolute` and inherit the natural `z-index` stacking order implied in the markup.

Note, I changed some other settings so I could see what I was doing (for instance, `opacity: 1` and the `background: color` for some elements). I don't know if what you have constitutes a (known/unknown) IE rendering bug or not, but cleaning up the approach seems to solve whatever is going on.

**EDIT**

IE < ver. 9 needs a [different `opacity` syntax](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html):

```
#arrow-nav li a {
    margin-top:-35px;
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    height:70px;
    overflow:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* For IE6/7 */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; /* IE 8 */
    background: #fdf;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    text-indent:-1000px;
    /*z-index: 1000;*/
}

...

#arrow-nav li a.show-opacity {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE6/7 */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)"; /* IE 8 */
}

$('#arrow-nav li')
    .mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find('a').addClass('show-opacity');
    })
    .mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find('a').removeClass('show-opacity');
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6w5BN/8/

Comment: Thank you very much, that is very kind of you. However, I tried this code myself when I was debugging the other day and it didnt work. After looking at it further, I do not think the problem is with CSS as even if I put a border around it and it displays at the front, the 'mouseenter' event still does not fire. It only fires if I place my mouse over the rounded corner. Maybe there is a bug with jQuery and HTML 5 figures. I cannot see what else could be causing this

Comment: Without seeing your actual jQuery code, I don't want to speculate ("bugs" often turn out to be "misunderstandings" or something else, IMO). See my edit for a `mouseenter/mouseleave` approach that leverages IE's previous support for [`opacity`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html).

Comment: I have found the problem and it is related to what @Zensar mentioned originally. Please see my question edit that I will post in a minute. Thank you very much and sorry to waste your time

Answer (score 0):

You are using HTML 5 tags in page. Which poly fill you are using for IE, since IE7-9 involved. It may be due to that also.

IE z-index stacking order is different from other browsers. Its z-index order is based on parent element.

Comment: Nothing to do with this. I have debugged and I have written a fix to make HTML 5 compatible with IE 7 and 8. IE 9 already supports it.

Comment: okay. Try this one -

   Remove position absolute from - #arrow-nav
 
   nav {
     position:absolute;
     z-index:500;
     width:100%;
   }

   #carousel-holder{
     position:relative;
     z-index:200;
     width:100%;
   }

 adjust the z-index of lis.

Comment: Nope, afraid not. However I think I may have made a step forward. Please read my edit in the question, will post in a min.

Answer (score -1):

You have `display: none` set on `header#carousel nav ul#arrow-nav li a`.

Comment: As I said in the question, please ignore these values as they are irrelevant. This is changed with jQuery

Comment: Apologies, can you provide a link showing the code in-situ? The LIs show up in IE9 for me.